How to create a zabbix trigger based on item from other host
My firewall is forwarding log to syslog server. I am creating a zabbix trigger to capture certain event on the log. I need the zabbix trigger to show on firewall host instead of syslog server host. How can I do it?
I have tried configuring the trigger on the firewall host based on syslog server item but the alert auto adjust to the syslog host instead of firewall host
